# SwiftUI - Specifying preferredColorScheme for only certain pages

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have set a preferred color scheme for the whole App

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    @StateObject private var settings = Settings.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            GeometryReader { _ in
                ApplicationView()
                    .preferredColorScheme(settings.themeMode.colorScheme)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I have a certain page that I would like to override the preferredColorScheme (only for that page)

So I put

```swift
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // ... my code
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(.light)
    }
```

But it does not work :c

Do you know of a way? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/preferredcolorscheme(_:)):

> Use one of the values in `ColorScheme` with this modifier to set a preferred color scheme for the nearest enclosing presentation, like a popover, a sheet, or a window. The value that you set overrides the user’s Dark Mode selection for that presentation.

This means that if you had a view that you wanted to show in a sheet, popover, or window you'd be able to change the color scheme.

**Update: I found this on [nilcoalescing.com](https://nilcoalescing.com/blog/ReadingAndSettingColorSchemeInSwiftUI/#setting-color-scheme-environment-value)**

You can see the result here:

You'll need to go into your asset catalog and set up a color set that has a light and dark color. It doesn't seem to change the background out of the box, but maybe there is something I'm missing.

In any case if you have a color set that has different colors for light and dark you can use this snippet to see how they change.

Note: I have set `preferredColorScheme(.light)` in my `App`.

If you need a full bleed background color, you can use a combination of `frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)` and `ignoresSafeArea()`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink {
                MyCustomView()
                    .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
            } label: {
                Text("Go to dark view")
            }

            NavigationLink {
                MyCustomView()
                    .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
            } label: {
                Text("Go to light view")
            }

        }
    }
}

struct MyCustomView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Text 2")
            .padding()
            .background(Color("MyColor"))
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That sadly does nothing but setting the background to dark
It wont affect assets, colors, etc... that change depending on the colorscheme

Comment: @cgutierr I updated the answer. Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Also, if you want to have two views on the same screen showing different color schemes, you can just stick these in a VStack or HStack and see the result.

Comment: The .environment works like a charm, thanks nick :D

Comment: Glad to hear that @cgutierr! Can you mark this as the accepted answer if you feel it answers the question?